# python ascii values split into list to convert into string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

string of ascii values are given how can i split these ascii values and convert to string

given ascii values:87101108991111091013211611132112121116104111110

How to separate above input in list like below

[87,101,108,99,111,109,101,32,116,111,32,112,121,116,104,111,110]

in python

Comment: You can't. The conversion is ambitious.

Comment: If all ascii values are represented as 3 digit numbers or if the expected ascii values are in between 32-122, it may be possible

Comment: Can you anyhow limit the amount of possible ascii values? For instance only characters of the alphabet and numbers? How did you obtain the given row of numbers -- maybe something can be done *before* you have them as string ...

Answer (score 1):

If you can limit the values then you can `iterate` over the string constructing a number until it falls in the range of values, save and proceed.

Here's my *ambitious* simple generator that yields numbers that fall within `ord(' ')` and `ord('z')`:

```
In []:
def g(s):
    v = 0
    for c in s:
        v = v*10 + int(c)
        if ord(' ') <= v <= ord('z'):
            yield v
            v = 0

''.join(chr(c) for c in g('87101108991111091013211611132112121116104111110'))

Out[]:
'Welcome to python'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex. Assuming that the input ascii values are only for string, you can split the input data with (A-65 to z-122)

```
>>> import re
>>> map(int,filter(None,re.split(r'([6-9][0-9])|(1[0-1][0-9])|(12[0-2])',s)))
[87, 101, 108, 99, 111, 109, 101, 32, 116, 111, 32, 112, 121, 116, 104, 111, 110]
```

Splitting with 3 digit integer and two digit integer will also do!

```
>>> map(int,filter(None,re.split(r'(1[0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9])',s)))
[87, 101, 108, 99, 111, 109, 101, 32, 116, 111, 32, 112, 121, 116, 104, 111, 110]
```

Comment: How did you get `32`?

Comment: @AChampion even i had same doubt.

Comment: its just splitting.. so once the regex patten is not matched, the value is splitted!

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
a = '87101108991111091013211611132112121116104111110'
data = map(int, filter(None, re.split("([3-9][0-9]|1[0-2][0-9])", a)))
''.join(chr(i) for i in data)
#=>'Welcome to python'
```